# alert summary of customer items bought in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im having trouble with doing alert with my javascript code. Firstly my website page is a checkout page. I want my alert to summarise what the customer ordered. Customers can select the product by ticking the checkbox and selecting how many of the items checked they want. there is also a total price field to show the customer how much they are going to pay. The alert will summarise what they bought.

example

"you have ordered: iphone, quantity: 1, price: £300 playstation 4, quantity: 3 price: £350

"you will pay: £650"

the alert should pop up when the button "place order" is clicked.

I'm having difficulties trying to do alert in my javascript code

my website is a checkout website. customers can choose products by ticking the checkbox and select the quantity for that product. there is also a field where they total price is displayed automatically.

I need an alert to summarise the customer order.
for example:

"you have ordered: iphone, price: £300, quantity: 2. television, price:£400, quantity: 1"
"total price which must be paid: £1000"

can you please implement this into my code please. I will be so happy.

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <head>
  <style>
    img {padding:10px 70px;}
    .buttons {text-align: center}
    .quantity { padding:5px; width:20px; border: 2px solid #112315; }
    legend {text-align: center; font-family: fantasy; font-size:30px;}
    fieldset {border:0;}
    label {float:left;width:20%; text-align:right; font-weight:bold;margin-right:10px; }    
    .check {margin-left:289px;}
    .total {float: right;}
    h2 {text-align: center} 
  </style>

<script>
 function total(frm) {
   var tot         = 0;
   var checkboxes  = document.forms[frm.id].elements["checkbox"];
   var quants      = document.forms[frm.id].elements["quantity"];

   for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) 
   {
     if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
      {
        // if tabIndex correctly specified
        if (checkboxes[i].tabIndex == quants[i].tabIndex)
            // add to total
            tot += Number(checkboxes[i].value) * Number(quants[i].value);
      }
  }
document.getElementById("totalDiv").firstChild.data = "£" + tot;
if (tot >= 200){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#BCBCFF";
}
if (tot >= 700){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFA3";
}
if (tot >= 1000){
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightskyblue";
} 
if (tot >= 1500){
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#66FF99";
}   

}

function validateFields() {

  var x=document.forms["Form"]["fName"].value;
  if (x=="")
   {
     alert("First Name must be filled out");
     return false;
   }

   var y=document.forms["Form"]["lName"].value;
   if (y=="")
   {
     alert("Last Name must be filled out");
     return false;
   }

var z=document.forms["Form"]["Address"].value;
if (z=="")
 {
  alert("Address must be filled out");
  return false;
 }

var a=document.forms["Form"]["Town"].value;
if (a=="")
 {
  alert("Town must be filled out");
  return false;  
 }

var b=document.forms["Form"]["Postcode"].value;
if ( b=="")
 {
  alert("Postcode must be filled out");
  return false; 
 }
}      


</script>


</head>

<body>
<form action="nextpage" method="post" id="theForm">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Choose your Products</legend>
    <table style="padding:2px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="buttons">
                <div>
     Mobile  <br>   <input tabindex="1" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="200"         onclick="total(this.form);" />£200</div>
                <input tabindex="1" name="quantity" min="0" max="5" type="number"         class="quantity" value="1" onclick="total(this.form);" />
            </td>
            <td class="buttons">
                <div>
                Television <br> <input tabindex="2" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="450"         onclick="total(this.form);" />£450</div>
                <input tabindex="2" name="quantity" min="0" max="5" type="number"          class="quantity" value="1" onclick="total(this.form);" />
            </td>
            <td class="buttons">
                <div>
                   Playstaion 4 <br> <input tabindex="3" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"         value="350"          onclick="total(this.form);" />£350</div>
                <input tabindex="3" name="quantity" min="0" max="5" type="number"         class="quantity" value="1" onclick="total(this.form);" />
             </td>
            <td class="buttons">
                <div>
                 Hi-Fi <br> <input tabindex="4" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="150"         onclick="total(this.form);" />£150</div>
                <input tabindex="4" name="quantity" min="0" max="5" type="number"         class="quantity" value="1" onclick="total(this.form);" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

---

```
<form name="Form" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateFields()" method="post">
<fieldset>
<h2> Personal Details</h2>

<p> <label for="Title"> Title:</label>  
<select name="Title">
    <option value="Mr" selected=""> Mr </option>
    <option value="Mrs"> Mrs </option>
    <option value="Miss"> Miss </option>
    <option value="Ms"> Ms </option>
    <option value="Dr"> Dr </option>
 </select>

</p><p> <label for="first name">First Name*:</label>  
<input type="text" name="fName" size="20" autofocus=""> </p>

<p> <label for="last name">Last Name*:</label> 
<input type="text" name="lName" size="20"> </p>

<p> <label for="address">Address*:</label> 
<input type="text" name="Address" size="40"> </p>

<p> <label for="town">Town*:</label> 
<input type="text" name="Town" size="20"> </p>

<p> <label for="postcode">Postcode*    :</label>  
<input type="text" name="Postcode" size="8"> </p>

<p> <label for="email address">Email address:</label> 
<input type="email" id="Email" placeholder="name@my.westminster.ac.uk" size="30"></p>

<p> <label for="Telephone">Telephone:</label>  
<input type="text" name="Telephone" size="20"> </p>

 <div>
<input type="button" class='check' value="Check Details"  onclick='return validateFields()'/>
 </div>    

 <div id="totalDiv" class= 'total'>£0</div>
 <br>       
 <div> <input type="button" class= 'total' value="Place Order" onclick="total(this.form)"/> </div>
</fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: can someone answer this please. It would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The 'Place Order' button, when clicked, calls total(this.form). But this button is inside the 'Personal Details' form, so you are passing the wrong form to total.